# Git is not tracking some of my files, old images on production side, nothing untracked in git status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx, capistrano

I have this strange issue that my git push origin master and cap deploy it not updating to the latest code and images on production server. I still have old images that I updated localy a long time ago and changes still not reflected.

- Is there a way to reset a remote git repo and upload a clean latest version of your local to it?
- Or other ways to debug, git status shows *no* untracked files so I really don't get where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an SSH timeout on cap deploy, wich I dident have noticed. Resulting in not all commits uploaded thus not seeing my latest commited changes. 
Had to upgrade ssh timeout on server.

Answer (score 1):

check your `.gitignore` file, you could have a line there ignoring these files or entire folders.

check your `deploy.rb` and multistage deploy files in `/deploy` folder to make sure that you are using correct branch (master)

When you update an image, commit, push to remote and do `cap production deploy:pending` do you see your commit listed there as pending deployment?

Comment: thx for the post, but ive checked the gitignore there are no directory's listed, only a few normal excluded files